# mysqli fetch only a specified amount of chars from row?

Tags: php, mysqli

i have been searching around the internet for a mysqli string manipulation function that will only fetch a specified amount of characters from the table row,
the closest thing i could find was the mysql LEFT() that works like this:

```
"SELECT LEFT(content, 20) FROM  articles WHERE id='1'"
```

So what this does is it gets only 20 characters from this row, but when i try to do this in my code which is this one

```
$sql = "SELECT id,byid,LEFT(content, 25),date_added FROM articles WHERE id='1' LIMIT 10";
$query = mysqli_query($database, $sql);
```

I can fetch all the other rows except the content one, i did some research and what i realized
was that every example of the LEFT(row, int) were mysql examples and not mysqli, 
I now i can achieve what i need with the php substr(); function but the content thats going to be fetched is really big and i don't want to slow down my website by downloading to much data that's not going to be used on the browser,

thank you :)

Comment: have you tried the MySQL substr function: http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substr-function.php ? I think in your case (and in most cases) that would be a better option.

Comment: did you try to give a name to your calculated column? `SELECT id, byid, LEFT(content, 25) as cut_content, date_added FROM articles WHERE id='1' LIMIT 10`

Comment: hello @Pascamel thank you for your answer, i now understand why it was not working when i was fetching the data i was doing it like this $row[content]; so it wasent fetching anything

Comment: @Maximus2012 thank you very much i got it working now like this $sql = "SELECT id,byid,LEFT(content, 25) FROM articles WHERE byid='$url_id' LIMIT 10";
  $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $articleid = $row["id"];
    $byid = $row["byid"];
    $content = $row["LEFT(content, 25)"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. a database you are working with is **still MySQL**. While mysqli is just a *set of PHP functions* to work with mysql database.
2. to solve this silly problem just add an *alias*

   ```
   SELECT id,byid,LEFT(content, 25) as cut,date_added FROM articles WHERE id='1' LIMIT 10";
   ```
3. What you **really** need from mysqli is **prepared statements**. A variable should never go into query directly but via **placeholder** only